# Fire off code after popup in error function

Tags: angular

I am trying to execute code after a popup is closed. Here is my code

```
  onCompleteRegistration(accessCode: string) {
    this.loader.start();
    this.myService.completeSignup(this.token)
      .subscribe((resp) => {
        if (resp) { 
           ...
        } else {
           ...
        }
        this.loader.stop();
      }, (error) => {
        this.loader.stop();
        this.errorService.openErrorPopup('Failed to complete registration. Please contact your HR representative.');
        window.location.href = ...

      });
  }
```

I am trying to make the window.location.href only fire after the popup is closed. Is there a way to do it in this function or do I have to manipulate my popup function

Comment: does the "errorService" provide any onClose method that you can listen to? if now you can make it like that.

Comment: do you want popup or open page when popup accept

Comment: I want to open the page after popup is accepted

Answer (score 0):

Does anything stop you from call

```
window.location.href = ...
```

from the completion handler of your subscriber instead of the error handler?

Comment: this currently fires even while the popup is open. I am trying to make it only fire after the popup is closed. something like  (error) => {popup} .then window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

The "**subscribe**" has 3 branches: onNext, onError and onCompleted.
I suppose you should add the 3rd branch - the onCompleted one.
See the sample below for the 3 branches:

```
this._heroService.addHero(this.hero).subscribe(
      hero=> this.hero= hero,
      error => console.log("Error: ", error),
      function(){ this._router.navigate(['HeroDetail', { id: this.hero.id }]) }
    );
```

Maybe you should add your redirect in the 3rd branch/section, which seems to be missing from your code.
https://aigeec.com/angularjs-2-do-something-when-my-observable-is-complete/